# Error E013 namespace "boost::asio" has no member "io_context"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, boost-asio

I'm new to Boost and I'm trying to use it with C++. I'm using boost_1_82_0-msvc-14.1-64.exe on Visual Studio 2017. I've written some code that reads COM port data and I've tried my best to fix it, but for some reason, no matter what I do, I get the same errors. The first error I received was 'PCH Warning: header stop not at file scope,' which I tried to fix with #define no_init_all, but it doesn't seem to work as I'm still getting the error. I've seen that having an older version of Boost can lead to this, but I have the latest version of Boost. So, I'm unsure what can be done here.

1. errors include:
2. E0135 namespace "boost::asio" has no member "io_context"
3. E0135 namespace "boost::asio" has no member "serial_port"
4. E0135 namespace "boost::asio" has no member "read_until"
5. E0135 namespace "boost::asio" has no member "dynamic_buffer"

```
    #if (_MSC_VER >= 1915)
    #define no_init_all deprecated
    #endif

    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <string>
    #include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>

struct SensorData {
    float heading;
    float magneticNorth;
    float magneticSouth;

};

SensorData readSerialData() {

    boost::asio::io_context io;
    boost::asio::serial_port port(io, "COM3");
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));

    SensorData sensorData;
    std::string sensorDataStr;
    std::size_t headingPos, magNorthPos, magSouthPos;
    std::string headingStr, magNorthStr, magSouthStr;

    while (true)
    {
        boost::asio::read_until(port, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(sensorDataStr), '\n'); // Read until a newline character is received
        headingPos = sensorDataStr.find("Heading:"); // Find the position of "Heading:" in the string
        if (headingPos != std::string::npos) {
            headingStr = sensorDataStr.substr(headingPos + 9); // Extract the heading value as a string
            sensorData.heading = std::stof(headingStr); // Convert the heading string to a float
        }
        magNorthPos = sensorDataStr.find("Magnetic North:"); // Find the position of "Magnetic North:" in the string
        if (magNorthPos != std::string::npos) {
            magNorthStr = sensorDataStr.substr(magNorthPos + 16); // Extract the magnetic north value as a string
            sensorData.magneticNorth = std::stof(magNorthStr); // Convert the magnetic north string to a float
        }
        magSouthPos = sensorDataStr.find("Magnetic South:"); // Find the position of "Magnetic South:" in the string
        if (magSouthPos != std::string::npos) {
            magSouthStr = sensorDataStr.substr(magSouthPos + 16); // Extract the magnetic south value as a string
            sensorData.magneticSouth = std::stof(magSouthStr); // Convert the magnetic south string to a float
        }

        if (headingPos != std::string::npos && magNorthPos != std::string::npos && magSouthPos != std::string::npos) {
            // All data has been received, so return the SensorData struct
            return sensorData;
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate help in understanding what I've done wrong and why.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're having trouble with precompiled headers you can either fix the issue or turn them off for a particular file or for the entire project. The rule for them is that for any source file that is set as using the precompiled header it must be the first include in that file. One source file in your project must be set to create the precompiled header and it should usually be the only header included in that file.

Comment: Does not it tell you first that some #include files are not found?

Comment: Apparently you *also* have an older version of the boost libraries. Specifically, older than the one that introduced `io_context` (1.66 or thereabouts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been playing around, and it seems it works in Visual Studio 2019, not 2017, and only in x86. This is very strange. I'm thinking that either there might be a bug or another version I must have installed a long time ago and forgotten about.

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select `Properties`.

In the project properties, select C/C++ > `General`.

Add the Boost include folder to the `Additional Include Directories` property. For example, if you installed Boost in C:\boost_1_75_0, you would add "C:\boost_1_75_0" to the include directories list.

Select Linker > `General`.

Add the Boost library folder to the `Additional Library Directories` property. For example, if you installed Boost in C:\boost_1_75_0, you would add "C:\boost_1_75_0\lib64-msvc-14.2" to the library directories list.

Select `Linker > Input`.

Add the Boost libraries to the project by specifying their names in the `Additional Dependencies` property.

Comment: I'm using boost_1_82_0 and ive already added it to the Additional Include Directories and Additional Library Directories, for the linker >Additional Dependencies I'm using these: ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib advapi32.lib Setupapi.lib